# How to change port hawtio, i run one megazord with spring camel rest and others

Tags: spring, apache-camel, spring-camel, hawtio

The title is auto-explicative.
Basically i have one project with many technology, and need camel to EIP.
I need hawtio run in another port.

My pom.xml
https://gist.github.com/andrealcantara/4a9d0a736f5c67ff0a6abc6d11e6febd

and my application.properties
https://gist.github.com/andrealcantara/9edbf756d165790a5dc7ad4e1b48fa2f

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For Hawtio on Spring Boot, it's open as the management endpoint so this applicaton property can control the port number.

```
management.server.port=10001
```

See this example for more info: https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/master/examples/springboot/src/main/resources/application.properties#L2